# Naive Bayes classification... not so efficient

Tags: statistics, classification, bayesian, naivebayes

I have a database of 10 million products (title, description, brand, category) as a learning dataset. I want to make an algorithm to classify around 10 000 products which do not have a category.

I made a little java program to train the algorithm using the Naive Bayes classifier, but when I input my 10 000 products, I only get 30% of correct answers....

Is there a way to improve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: NB is only as good as your feature vector and the size of the training set.

Comment: A Naive Bayes classifier is mathematically speaking indeed pretty naive and rather inflexible. If you want higher accuracy and flexibility you might want to use a decision tree. See this post for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317885/decision-tree-vs-naive-bayes-classifier